# There’s one letter (for you) to sign

Tags: existential-constructions

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by H&P says (Page 1394):

> (d) Infinitival extensions
>
> [11] i a. *A few replies are still **to come**.* b. *There are still a few replies **to come**.*
>
> ii a. *One letter is **(for you) to sign***. b. *There’s one letter **(for you) to sign**.*
>
> In [i] *a few replies* is understood as subject of the infinitival, while in [ii] *one letter* is understood as object of the infinitival – see Ch. 14, §6.3.

CGEL analyzes that [ia] and [ib] mean the same thing, and that [iia] and [iib] mean the same thing. But isn't *one letter (for you) to sign* in [iib] normally analyzed as an NP (especially when *for you* is omitted)?

Assuming that there are two possible analyses of [iib], one according to CGEL and the other treating *one letter (for you) to sign* as an NP, is [iib] inherently ambiguous?

In general, is the existential construction inherently ambiguous when accompanied by an added component such as a non-finite VP, an adjective phrase, or a preposition phrase at the end of the construction?

Comment: Different sources are likely to say different things. Are you asking about how CGEL views this collection of words, or are you asking how other grammatical authorities (or possibly some kind of folk grammar) might view them? And, are you assuming that "to sign" is a prepositional phrase modifying the noun phrase "one letter"?

Comment: @StuartF I would not interpret _There's one letter to sign_ to mean _One letter is to sign_. So, yes, _to sign_ in the former has to modify _letter_, at least for me. I don't think different grammars would be different as to what the most salient meaning should be.

Comment: I think your second mention of "[ib]" in your question should probably be "[iib]" but I would wholeheartedly recommend renumbering everything anyway -- you can still quote with the reference "(page 1394, renumbered for clarity)". However iia certainly doesn't mean the same as iib. Even "One letter is to sign, the other must be shredded" would be rather stilted even if it's understandable. But my opinion of Huddleston & Pullum is well known here. I'll shut up now.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for pointing it out. It's been corrected. It's not about whether you like CGEL or not, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @JK2 Unusually, I think your question could be unpacked for readers here. It's difficult to intuitively understand.

Comment: The only question I can see is _isn't one letter (for you) to sign in [iib] normally analyzed as an NP (especially when for you is omitted)?_ What do you mean "normally"? _One letter for you to sign_ is a noun phrase that's been done things to. How did _letter_ get from being the DO of _sign_  to being the first noun in the phrase? What category you place the revised node in is irrelevant; such categories have no consistent invariants.

Comment: @JohnLawler The *CGEL* analysis (which I don't understand at all) is that *one letter* and *(for you) to sign* are not a single constituent here, but two separate complements of *be* licensed by the existential construction. Unusually, I find the grammaticality judgements used in their arguments here very odd - and suspect others would too.

Comment: @Araucaria That sounds almost coherent, but why does one need two? And how do relative infinitives work? They hafta be related to relative clauses, but they're bloody mysterious.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. So you also find the grammaticality judgements there very odd. So do I. And my question is exactly that.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sometimes, one needs to treat them as two separate complements of _be_. For example, _There is no one to blame_ is more likely to mean "No one is to blame" than "There is no one who is to blame". So here, you do need two complements (_no one_ and _to blame_). I think the same analysis should be applied to [ib] _There are still a few replies to come._

Comment: @JohnLawler Apparently two are needed to account for sentences like "There are still to come a few replies" where it would be odd if to come were a modifier of the forthcoming NP. I don't get it in the other example, however. Although I can see it with *only* added: "There is only one letter for you to sign" As for relative infinitives, I've never been able to get my head round them properly

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Another confounding factor, if you will, is that the existence of a corresponding canonical form as in [a] examples of CGEL may not be a prerequisite for the two-complement analysis. For example, _There was a problem with my car_ cannot correspond to ? _A problem was with my car_, but _with my car_ is most likely to be a separate complement of _was_, at least in my view.

Comment: What confuses me most is that they give as ungrammatical: "**Those people going to be disadvantaged by the new tax system will have to be compensated in some way*" <--That seems perfectly grammatical to me!

Comment: I think we've entered the Epicycle Creation Center. These do not seem like syntactic problems to me; I'm unconcerned with the grammaticality judgements in CGEL and what analyses they invented to explain them.

Comment: It's a theory, and a problematic one at that, prima facie. How could it be "true"? You'd hafta demonstrate it with data, not arguments. Like I said, I'm unconcerned with the opinions of CGEL authors, just as I am with Chomsky's.

Comment: @JohnLawler It seems more like it's the other way round (i.e. examples to motivate analyses). I don't really understand the thinking or the examples though (the issue is one of constituency), but it impinges on other questions which do concern me. For example, does the verb *be* have a maximum valency of 1 (in terms of VP internal complements)? I've always assumed that it does, and used that in arguments quite often. But the CGEL analysis here posits *be* taking two VP internal complements, which if true stuffs up those arguments completely.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. It's interesting that using the fixed phrase _be going to_ without _be_ seems perfectly grammatical to you. Can you then even say this? _Those people **gonna** be disadvantaged by the new tax system will have to be compensated in some way._

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Oh, and here's another counterexample, I think, of _be_ having a maximum valency of 1: _Life is there to be lived._

Comment: @JohnLawler In an effort to make it less about CGEL's grammaticality judgments, I've edited the question.